# How do I open my closed form through the notifyicon in the taskbar?

Tags: c#, winforms, notifyicon

Currently I am developing a windows form application in c# that has several forms.

I am running a background form that operates the notifyicon property that allows the icon to appear in the taskbar.

When I launch the program, it will launch a loginForm, after which logging in it will go into a mainForm. After closing the mainForm, the application does not close yet, which in this case works like Windows Live Messenger.

How do I make my program in a way that after I the mainForm, through double clicking it will bring the form back up? (Like how MSN works.)

Or is it a better solution for me to close the whole application when I press the X button in the title bar. Which brings up another problem for me as I cant seem to exit the application when I close other forms other than the main form.

Comment: You cannot open a closed form, that fails with ObjectDisposedException.  Create a new one.  I have to guess that your (hidden) login form keeps the app running.  It isn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you have NotifyIcon on your main form. Subscribe on the `DoubleClick` event of this control and change state of your main form in the handler:

```
    private void notifyIcon1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Show();
        this.Visible = true;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `Visible` property of the form to `true`/`false`. Or you could call `Show()`/`Hide()`.